# Using jQuery to grab the link text (if it has it) or the id of an image (if it's an image link)

Tags: jquery, text, find

I want to use jQuery to determine if a link is a text link or an image link. If it's a text link, I want to grab the text. If it's an image link, I want to get the id of the image. I tried using .text() for the text links, but this also returns true for my image links.

```
function get_link_content(object) {

            if($(object).text()) {
                var link_content = $(object).text();
            }
// even if it's an image link, this ^^ always returns true
            else if($(object).find('img')) {
                if($(object).find('img').attr('id')) {
                    var link_content = $(object).find('img').attr('id');
                }
                else {
                    var link_content = 'unidentified';
                }
            }

            return link_content;
        }
```

By text link, I mean:

```
<a href="#">This is a text link</a>
```

By image link, I mean:

```
 <a href="#"><img id="the-id" src="#"></a>
```

Is there another method I should be using besides .text()?

Comment: you could swap your logic; check for an image and if it doesn't have one then grab the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a cleaned up and slightly optimized version of your code:

```
function get_link_content(object) {
  var $object = $(object), // Cache the element for faster execution
      $img = $object.find('img'),
      link_content,
      id;

  if (!$img.length) { // Does the object element not have an image?
    link_content = $object.text();
  } else {
    id = $img.attr('id'); // Get the image ID (if it exist)

    if (id.length) { // Was there an ID?
      link_content = id;
    } else {
      link_content = 'unidentified';
    }
  }

  return link_content;
}
```

**Edit:** Here's a further optimized version (with a jQuery element passed).

```
function get_link_content($object) {
  var $img = $object.find('img'),
      link_content;

  if (!$img.length) { // Does the object element not have an image?
    link_content = $object.text();
  } else {
    link_content = $img.attr('id'); // Get the image ID (if it exist)

    if (!link_content.length) { // Was there no ID?
      link_content = 'unidentified';
    }
  }

  return link_content;
}
```

As you can see, I've removed the `id`, since it's to be stored in the `link_content` anyway (if the `id` existed and had a value). This means that it will be slightly faster when it encounters an image that has an `id`, since it doesn't have to assign the id value to the variable `id` and then assign `id` to `link_element` in a second step if there was a value. It's also a bit shorter than the first version, which increases readability a little bit.

Comment: Here lies another question -- what if I already cached the object and used the variable where it is stored within my function call? Is it still necessary to cache the object within the function?

Comment: If the object that you pass is a jQuery object, then it will be faster. Just change the function section to: `function get_link_content($object)` and remove `$object = $(object), // Cache the element for faster execution`. The reason why I name the variable `$object` instead of `object` is to indicate that it's a jQuery element.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: No problem. There's one more thing we could optimize. I'll make one more edited version underneath the version you accepted as an answer. Stay tuned. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if( $('img', $(object)).length ){
//object has a img as child
}
else{
//object doesnt have
}
```

or

```
var myText = $('img', $(object)).length ? $('img', $(object)).attr('id') 
             : $(object).text();
```

or as a function

```
function get_link_content(object) {
    return $('img', $(object)).length ? $('img', $(object)).attr('id') 
                 : $(object).text();
}
```

or

```
return ( $('img', $(object)) && $('img', $(object)).attr('id') ) || $(object).text();
```

Changed all length to has() from @undefined 's suggestion and then reverted back to length after reading docs of 'has()' :P

Comment: The last one makes it sure that no one understands your code easily :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery object's `length` property:

```
var $obj = $(object);
if(!$obj.children().length) {
    var link_content = $obj.text();
} else {
    var link_content = $('img', $obj).attr('id');
    // ...
}
```

<sub>Note that you can cache the `$(object)` instead of making jQuery objects several times.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the optimization tip. Is the best approach to just store the object in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_link_content(e) {
        if($(e).find('img').length != 0) {
            if($(e).find('img').attr('id')) {
                var link_content = $(e).find('img').attr('id');
            } else {
                var link_content = 'unidentified';
            }
        } else {
            var link_content = $(object).text();
        }
        return link_content;
    }
```

`$(object).find('img')` - this will always return jQuery object, and object is always true. To check if jQuery found some element you should use length property.

By the way: $(e).find('img').attr('id') - doin this many times is not the best approach. It is better to get the value once and put it into some temporary variable.

Comment: By "get the value once" do you mean store the object in a variable?

Comment: Yeah. Something like this: `var tmpId = $(e).find('img').attr('id'); if(tmpId) {
                var link_content = tmpId;`. The reason is that DOM operations are not so fast. Well, maybe in your case difference is not so big, but anyway...

Comment: If I cache the img object, does it help when I go to retrieve the id attribute later?

Comment: If you are asking if ther will be some speed difference - yes, it will be faster than in your initial code (but difference will be almost invisible for just a few elements) - jquery object keeps a refference to selected objects and will not do any search again.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_link_content(object) {
    var link_content = 'unidentified';
    var $img = $(object).find('img');
    if(!$img.length){
      //no image found
      //get the text
      var $txt = $(object).text();
      if($txt.length){
          link_content = $txt;
      }
    }else{
      //there's an image
      link_content = $img.attr('id');
    }
    return link_content;
}
```